# Lighttpd single subdomain Redirect/rewrite

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain, lighttpd

I am using lighttpd, and I would like to redirect a subdomain to a regular url, but keep the subdomain showing in the browser.

For example, if I have the following url: http://blog.test.com/...

and I would like to redirect it to: http://test.com/blog/...

but still show blog.test.com/... as the URL in the browser.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Still having problems finding a solution to this. Is it possible to just rewrite http://test.com/blog/... as http://blog.test.com/...?

Answer (score 1):

You need `proxy-core.rewrite-request` with something like that:

```
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "blog.test.com" {
    proxy-core.rewrite-request = (
      "_uri" => ( ".*" => "/blog/$1" ),
      "Host" => ( ".*" => "test.com" ),
    )
  }
```

Jump to the `proxy-core.rewrite-request` part [of the doc](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxyCore).

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to keep blog.test.com in the browser URL though. It's something little that I'm missing isn't it?

Comment: I never tried `proxy-core.rewrite-request` but according to the documentation, this is what you are looking for. But I'm really not sure about what I wrote but I think this is a good start to go for you.